Maximisations over LOCC measurement protocols
I have a quantity that I want to calculate by maximising over LOCC measurement protocols. How does one even approach this problem, both analytically or numerically? Has any work been done on the same? What are the kinds of approaches one needs to use when we encounter such problems? I could find papers finding upper bounds on mutual information when we only consider LOCC strategies, but none talk about how to approach them numerically if we wish to calculate them (here, mutual information) exactly.
Any ideas or references to papers would be very helpful.

This seems to general. If you describe what quantity you have to maximize, it would be easier to answer. -- Other than that, there is this thing called "separable superoperators" (IIRC) which are a larger class than LOCC, but easier to characterize.

@NorbertSchuch I was looking to calculation $I_{acc}^{LOCC}$, commonly referred to as locally accessible information. It is calculated by maximising mutual information over all LOCC measurement protocols. Although an upper bound for multipartite systems for this has been found, it's not really useful as it's not asymptotically reachable and depending on the case, it can be higher than the Holevo Bound - therefore making the bound practically useless.
